# Play video using Data content without saving

Tags: ios, swift

My question is simple...

I have an array of bytes or actually a data of my video, and I want to play it.

Every library that I use, saves the  Data & gets the path of saved Data as URL.

But I don't want to save the Data...

Kindly help me what to do to play a video using bytes or Data, without saving it.

Comment: Is there a reason you _don't want to save the data_ ?

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi yes , cause my file is encrypted , and if I decrypt it and then resave it after that I give the new path which is encrypted to my video player , but I want it to execute the encryption in my app and not to save it in my memory again .. my only way is to play video from content as Data ...

Comment: I don't think there is any other way other than `URL` for playing a video.

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't want to save the Data

Yes, you do. You never want to play a video from data held in memory; it's way too big and will crash your app. And in fact the system isn't even set up to play video out of memory! It's set up to play video out of files.

So, as you obtain the data you save it, and in order to play it, you supply the file URL where you saved it. That's the right way.

Comment: dear @matt I save my video file in memory , but it is encrypted , and if I decrypt it and then resave it , what is the purpose of encrypting that ?!!!!!
because of this my one and only way is to read the decrypted content as Data in my application without saving it ... 
I am doing the same way with my music player but I couldn't find a way to do that for my video actually the entrance of video player functions are URL and the path of my file but I told you at the first that this is not what I want ... 
Any idea ?